# Running weka from command line - cannot find class NaiveBayes

Tags: command-line, weka, bayesian, classification

I am trying to run a Weka classification from the commmand line, but my code:

```
java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t file1.arff -T file2.arff -p
```

comes up with the error message:

"Could not find the main class: weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes. Program will exit."

I am running the command in the directory containing weka.jar.
How come it cannot find the classifier?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding an explicit classpath, e.g.

`java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t file1.arff -T file2.arff -p`

Some JVMs do not infer that the jar file you need is in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

**WEKA's readme**

> [image]

**Path solution**

You can modify your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export R_HOME="/Applications/R.app/Contents/MacOS/R"    #for WEKA MLR R plugin 
export CLASSPATH="/Applications/weka-3-9-1/weka.jar"    #for WEKA commandline
export WEKAINSTALL="/Applications/weka-3-9-1"

export WEKA_HOME="/Applications/weka-3-9-1"
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;$WEKA_HOME/weka.jar
export HEAP_OPTION=-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m
export JAVA_COMMAND java $HEAP_OPTION
```

and then you should be able to run

```
java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t $WEKAINSTALL/data/iris.2D.arff -T $WEKAINSTALL/data/iris.2D.arff
```